# In Python, how do I create an edge collection and document for an arangodb?

Tags: python, arangodb

I'm trying to write a python script to create an edge collection and insert edges into my arango database. The ArangoDB documentation includes how to create a document collection and a document in that collection:

`UsersCollection= db.createCollection(name = "Users")
 doc = usersCollection.createDocument()
doc["name"] = "Tesla"
doc.save()`

However, when I try to adapt this to creating an edge collection or adding an edge to an edge collection, it doesn't work. The first step doesn't allow for changing the collection to any type other than document. Since that's the first step to selecting a collection to reference, I haven't actually gotten to the step of trying to add to an edge collection that already exists.

Is this possible?

## Update

I ended up going about this in a different way by using the API. My issue was that I was trying to do a bulk import of NSJ of my edges. When I attempted to do an import as you would a document collection, it would create a document collection followed by related issues of import an edge to a document collection. To fix this, I did the follow:

Step 1:
Manually created my collection with my edge collection name within the db interface.

Step 2: I then wrote this code, passed my NSF edges as `f` and my edge collection name as `name`.

```
def upload_Collection(f, name):
   filez = open(f).read()
   url = "/_api/import?type=auto&collection=%s&createCollection=false&overwrite=true&waitForSync=false&complete=false&details=true" % (
    name)
   r = requests.post(url, data=filez)
   return r.text
```

Sorry it took me so long to get back to this! I hope this is help to others!

### Notes

I chose not use the ArangoDB python driver because, honestly, I found it confusing to actually implement. Thanks for the suggestion anyway, @dothebart !

Comment: "it doesn't work" <- Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: The first step doesn't allow for changing the collection to any type other than document. Since that's the first step to selecting a collection to reference, I haven't actually gotten to the step of trying to add to an edge collection that already exists.

Comment: did you try these: http://arangodb-python-driver.readthedocs.org/en/latest/edges.html

Comment: @ChristopherHooper Is this still a problem? Did the link provided by dothebart help you?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going about this in a different way by using the API. My issue was that I was trying to do a bulk import of NSJ of my edges. When I attempted to do an import as you would a document collection, it would create a document collection followed by related issues of import an edge to a document collection. To fix this, I did the follow:

Step 1:
Manually created my collection with my edge collection name within the db interface.

Step 2: I then wrote this code, passed my NSF edges as `f` and my edge collection name as `name`.

```
def upload_Collection(f, name):
   filez = open(f).read()
   url = "/_api/import?type=auto&collection=%s&createCollection=false&overwrite=true&waitForSync=false&complete=false&details=true" % (
    name)
   r = requests.post(url, data=filez)
   return r.text
```

Sorry it took me so long to get back to this! I hope this is help to others!

Answer (score 0):

There is available `className='Edges'` option in the `createCollection` constructor such as

```
from pyArango.connection import *

conn = Connection(username="root", password="") # set your password
db = conn.createDatabase(name="TestDB")

users = db.createCollection(name="User")
edges = db.createCollection(name="edges", className='Edges')

users.createDocument({'_key':u1, 'name':'Alice'}).save()
users.createDocument({'_key':u2, 'name':'Bob'}).save()
edges.createDocument({'_from':'User/u1', '_to':'User/u2'}).save()
```